# Cross join Redshift with sequence of dates

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I'd like to do following athena query with redshift, but so far it's been impossible to reproduce it. The query should be called in a `CREATE TABLE AS ()` statement, so generate_sequence() ideas might not work. Any ideas?

Athena query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM table_one t1
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(slice(sequence(t1.effective_date, t1.expiration_date, INTERVAL  '1' MONTH), 1 ,12)) AS t (sequence_date)
```

As requested I add an example to show what I'm trying to do. Basically I have a record with a validity interval (year units 1, 2, 3...) and I'd like to replicate it N time  times such that each new record is assigned to date YYYY-MM-DD + interval*12/N months (See examples)

Original record:

| Date | variables |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-06 | values |

To be (N=12 and interval of 1 year)

| Date | variables |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-06-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-07-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-08-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-08-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-10-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-11-06 | values/12 |
| 2021-12-06 | values/12 |
| 2022-01-06 | values/12 |
| 2022-02-06 | values/12 |
| 2022-03-06 | values/12 |
| 2022-04-06 | values/12 |

To be (N=4 and interval of two years)

| Date | variables |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-06 | values/2 |
| 2021-11-06 | values/2 |
| 2022-05-06 | values/2 |
| 2022-11-06 | values/2 |

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the best way to do this is with a re cursive CTE - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

Example - [Generate rows with incrementing dates based on just a starting date in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893537/generate-rows-with-incrementing-dates-based-on-just-a-starting-date-in-redshift/69901825#69901825)

What you seem to be doing is a little more complex than this example.  If you can't get it post some sample data that the experts here can use to create a sample query for you.

================================================

With the new info and the above recursive CTE process I came up with this:

```
drop table if exists table_one ;
create table table_one (
dt date,
info varchar(32),
n int,
y int);

insert into table_one values ('2021-05-06', 'record info here', 12, 1);
commit;

with recursive dates(dt, info, n, y, end_dt) as
( select dt::date, info, n, y, dateadd(year, y, dt)::date as end_dt
  from table_one
  union all
  select dateadd(months, 12 * y / n, dt)::date as dt, info, n, y, end_dt::date
  from dates d
  where d.dt < dateadd(month, -12 * y /n, end_dt)
  )
select dt, info from dates;
```

I'm not sure this is how you want to get N and year into the process but hopefully you can modify from here.  Just change the values of N and year in table_one insert statement and rerun the whole process to get your 2nd result.

Comment: Thanks for your help I already explored this path, but not sure whether it is going to work. I added some clarifications in the post so that it is more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: De nada.  Just paying if forward.